# Unix: Only increment counter per line in a sequence

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal

I'd like to execute a command that has the form

```
1 1
2 2
3 3
....
```

However, when I use the sequence `printf '%d %d \n' $(seq 1 1 10)` what I get is

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
...
```

Is there a way to specify that the counter shouldn't be incremented within the same line?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) for this also. Has the added benefit of running your command in parallel.

```
parallel echo {#} {#} ::: {1..3}
1 1
2 2
3 3
```

Comment: -k to ensure the order will remain the same.

Answer (score 1):

Use for:

```
for i in {1..10}; do
    echo "$i $i"
done
```